# Why I don't see any text on the text component when running the game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to see the "Hello World" text. But there is nothing.

Either if using `3D Object > 3D Text`
Or `UI > Text`
Or `UI > Text - TextMeshPro`

No matter what text component I'm using since there is no mesh renderer attached to it I'm getting exception so I'm adding to the Text component first a mesh renderer.

But then I'm getting exception say there is no TextMesh component attached to the new created texts so I'm changing this line :

```
var textmesh = newText.GetComponent<TextMesh>();
```

To

```
var textmesh = newText.GetComponent<Text>();
```

But still it's not working getting exception say textmesh is null.

So I changed the text component to UI > Text
Added to the text a MeshRenderer and now not getting exceptions/errors :

[image: Text]

And

[image: Text]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class AddTextToObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEngine.GameObject[] objectsToNumber;
    public UnityEngine.GameObject text;
    public float yPadding;
    public bool rotateNumbers = false;
    public float rotationSpeed = 10f;
    public bool textChild = false;
    public bool textAbove = false;
    public bool textInFront = false;
    public bool textOnFaces = false;

    private List<GameObject> newTexts = new List<GameObject>();
    private MeshRenderer[] renderer;
    private Vector3 newPos;

    private void Start()
    {
        renderer = new MeshRenderer[objectsToNumber.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToNumber.Length; i++)
        {
            GameObject newText = Instantiate(text);
            renderer[i] = newText.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();

            if (textAbove == true)
            {
                newPos = new Vector3
                (
                 objectsToNumber[i].transform.position.x,
                 ((objectsToNumber[i].transform.position.y + renderer[i].bounds.extents.y) + yPadding),
                   objectsToNumber[i].transform.position.z
                 );
            }

            if (textInFront == true)
            {
                newPos = new Vector3
                (
                 ((objectsToNumber[i].transform.position.x + renderer[i].bounds.extents.x) + yPadding),
                 objectsToNumber[i].transform.position.y,
                   objectsToNumber[i].transform.position.z
                 );
            }

            newText.transform.position = newPos;
            newText.transform.parent = transform;
            newText.name = i.ToString();
            newText.tag = "Number";
            newTexts.Add(newText);
            var textmesh = newText.GetComponent<TextMesh>();
            textmesh.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, -90, 0);

            if (textAbove == true)
            {
                textmesh.text = i.ToString();
            }

            if (textInFront == true)
            {
                textmesh.text = "Hello World";
            }
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (rotateNumbers == true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < newTexts.Count; i++)
            {
                newTexts[i].transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, 10 * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update :

Trying using TextMeshPro :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class AddTextToObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEngine.GameObject[] objectsToNumber;
    public UnityEngine.GameObject text;
    public float yPadding;
    public bool rotateNumbers = false;
    public float rotationSpeed = 10f;
    public bool textChild = false;
    public bool textAbove = false;
    public bool textInFront = false;
    public bool textOnFaces = false;

    private List<GameObject> newTexts = new List<GameObject>();
    private MeshRenderer[] renderer;
    private Vector3 newPos;

    private void Start()
    {
        renderer = new MeshRenderer[objectsToNumber.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToNumber.Length; i++)
        {
            GameObject newText = Instantiate(text);
            renderer[i] = objectsToNumber[i].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();

            if (textAbove == true)
            {
                newPos = new Vector3
                (
                 objectsToNumber[i].transform.position.x,
                 ((objectsToNumber[i].transform.position.y + renderer[i].bounds.extents.y) + yPadding),
                   objectsToNumber[i].transform.position.z
                 );
            }

            if (textInFront == true)
            {
                newPos = new Vector3
                (
                 ((objectsToNumber[i].transform.position.x + renderer[i].bounds.extents.x) + yPadding),
                 objectsToNumber[i].transform.position.y,
                   objectsToNumber[i].transform.position.z
                 );
            }

            newText.transform.position = newPos;
            newText.transform.SetParent(transform, false);
            newText.name = i.ToString();
            newText.tag = "Number";
            newTexts.Add(newText);
            var textmesh = newText.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
            textmesh.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, -90, 0);

            if (textAbove == true)
            {
                textmesh.text = i.ToString();
            }

            if (textInFront == true)
            {
                textmesh.text = "Hello World";
            }
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (rotateNumbers == true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < newTexts.Count; i++)
            {
                newTexts[i].transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, 10 * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the result is that the text is not close to the gameobjects. 
The text "Hello World" should be like stick/attached to each gameobject.

[image: Text]

And

[image: Text]

And what I want to do is to stick/attach the text "Hello World" to the face front side of each of the 3 cubes New Game, Options, Quit :

[image: Text]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is not a child of a [`Canvas`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UICanvas.html)

> The Canvas is the area that all UI
>    elements should be inside

any UI elements that are not under a `Canvas` in the hierarchy are not rendered.

---

There are two different kinds of text components in Unity. The legacy [`TextMesh`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextMesh.html) and `TextMeshPro` which work standalone **without** a `Canvas` and are used and positioned like 3D objects.

And there are the UGUI or UI components [`Text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Text.html) and `TextMeshProUGUI` which are used in combination with a `Canvas`.

So the "correct" replacement for `TextMeshPro` would **not** be a [`Text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Text.html) but rather a `TextMesh`. (I wouldn't go that direction though .. if you already have TMP stick with it .. it is better than the legacy UI `Text` and `TextMesh`.

---

You should also not add a `MeshRenderer` manually to the object! UI elements like [`Text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Text.html) and `TextMeshProUGUI` bring their own renderer with them. Maybe you should go through the [Unity UI Tutorial](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-canvas?playlist=17111) once.

Also checkout the [TextMeshPro Guide](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@1.3/manual/index.html)!

Comment: Still not working good. I updated my question with what I tried and what is my goal. The main goal is to stick/attach/put the text on the front side of the 3 gameobjects New Game, Options, Quit. In this case the 3 objects are cubes.

Comment: Well now you are using `TextMeshProUGUI` which is probably exactly what you don't want ... because now you will need a **WorldSpace** `Canvas` in order to make them visible .. I guess currently you have a `ScreenSpace Overlay` canvas?

Comment: Right, The Canvas is set to Screen Space - Overlay